# How to insert values and how to increase the row in runtime when needed in JTable where I make JTable using the NETBEANS visual GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, defaulttablemodel

How to insert values and how to increase the row in runtime when needed in JTable where I make JTable using the NETBEANS visual GUI??

```
     text_jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

 text_jTable.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

 text_jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
new Object [][] {
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null}
 },
new String [] {
    "#", "Start Time", "End Time", "Duration", "Text"
 }
 ) {
Class[] types = new Class [] {
    java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,      java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
   };

public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return types [columnIndex];
}
    });

text_jTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

      text_jTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);

   text_jTable.setEnabled(false);

 text_jTable.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

 text_jTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

 jScrollPane1.setViewportView(text_jTable);

 text_jTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
text_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
text_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
text_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
text_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
```

After creating the JTable by netbeans visual GUI, I can't underdtand how to increase the row number in runtime ..

Answer (score 4):

Get the table model of the table, cast it to [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), and use one of its `addRow()` methods:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) text_jTable.getModel();
model.addRow(theDataOfTheNewRow);
```

Understanding how a JTable works, and what the role of its model is, is crucial. You should not use a visual GUI designer if you don't understand the code it generates, and how to use the components it generates.

The [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is a very good (and free) resource to understand how Swing works.